# Using hibernate in Java EE app

Tags: java, hibernate, deployment, jakarta-ee

I am maintaining following structure for my project

Web - Web Project

Model - EJB Project

Persistence - Java project having data classes and their mapping for Hibernate

Pokuri - EAR Project

As we know we can give jar file to hibernate configuration to load mapping information from jar. As I deploy EAR on to server I just want to build SessionFactory from mapping files in Persistence jar. But I am unable to get the path for that jar. Plz guide me to get the jar path. Or suggest me the best way to build SessionFactory and bind the same to a JNDI name.

Comment: Was your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes I it is resolved after got familiar with class loaders and JarURlConnection APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this thread](http://seamframework.org/Community/HowToDeployJPAEntitiesInAnExtraJarFile) - it may contain useful information.

Also, make sure your jar is mapped in your `application.xml` as an ejb module.